# Ruby 2-D Array initialization error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new to Ruby and want to store a 4x4 input in a 2-D array.
**Input**

```
1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4
1 3 5 6
```

**My Code**

```
array1=Array.new(4,0) {Array.new(4,0)}
(1..4).each do |i|
    k=0
    gets.chomp.split(' ').each do |j|
        array1[i][k]=j.to_i
        k=k+1
    end
end
```

**Error I get**

NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):5:in`block (2 levels) in irb_binding'
        from (irb):4:in `each'
        from (irb):4:in`block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):2:in `each'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/irb:12:in`'

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(0..3).each do |i|` ?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You have exceeded the `Array` index while iterating from 1 to 4

You should be iterating from 0 to 3